# Did JUNO adjust it's orbit in order to fly over Clyde's spot again?

Tags: mission-design, photography, jupiter, juno, outreach

Phys.org's [Juno returns to 'Clyde's Spot' on Jupiter](https://phys.org/news/2021-05-juno-clyde-jupiter.html) says:

> The feature is informally named for amateur astronomer Clyde Foster of Centurion, South Africa, who discovered it in 2020 using his own 14-inch telescope. On June 2, 2020, just two days after Foster's initial discovery, Juno provided detailed observations of Clyde's Spot (upper image), which scientists determined was a plume of cloud material erupting above the top layers of the Jovian atmosphere just southeast of Jupiter's Great Red Spot, which is currently about 1.3 times as wide as Earth. These powerful convective outbreaks occasionally occur in this latitude band, known as the South Temperate Belt. The initial plume subsided quickly, and within a few weeks it was seen as a dark spot.

and later

> The upper image was taken on June 2, 2020, around 3:56 a.m. when the spacecraft was about 28,000 miles (45,000 kilometers) from Jupiter's cloud tops. The lower image was taken on April 15, 2021, at 4:58 p.m. PDT (7:58 p.m. EDT). At the time, the spacecraft was about 16,800 miles (27,000 kilometers) from Jupiter's cloud tops, at a latitude of about 30 degrees South. Another citizen scientist, Kevin M. Gill, processed both images from raw JunoCam data.

These are Perijoves 27 and 33 according to Wikipedia's [Juno (spacecraft); Timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juno_(spacecraft)#Timeline)

**Question(s):**

1. Was it just an accident that JUNO was able to take *what looks like* top-down images of the spot during both perijoves? Or did they make a small orbital correction in order to pass over it this time?
2. Are these in fact top-down images or have they been re-interpolated corrected for obliquity by the citizen-scientists who generated these particular images?

---

[image: Images of Clyde's spot; NASA/JPL-Caltech/SwRI/MSSS. Image processing by Kevin M. Gill]

Source: Phys.org's [Juno returns to 'Clyde's Spot' on Jupiter](https://phys.org/news/2021-05-juno-clyde-jupiter.html), Credit: Image data: NASA/JPL-Caltech/SwRI/MSSS. Image processing by Kevin M. Gill

Comment: potentially helpful: https://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/data_and_services/atmospheres_data/JUNO/logs/Time%20Line%20of%20Orbital%20Parameters-a%20-1-1.html